# Optimal method to create a large string containing several variables?

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

I want to create a string that contains many variables:

```
std::string name1 = "Frank";
std::string name2 = "Joe";
std::string name3 = "Nancy";
std::string name4 = "Sherlock";

std::string sentence;

sentence =   name1 + " and " + name2 + " sat down with " + name3;
sentence += " to play cards, while " + name4 + " played the violin.";
```

This should produce a sentence that reads

**Frank and Joe sat down with Nancy to play cards, while Sherlock played the violin.**

My question is: What is the optimal way to accomplish this?  I am concerned that constantly using the + operator is ineffecient.   Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `std::stringstream`, e.g.:

```
#include <sstream>
...

std::string name1 = "Frank";
std::string name2 = "Joe";
std::string name3 = "Nancy";
std::string name4 = "Sherlock";

std::ostringstream stream;
stream << name1 << " and " << name2 << " sat down with " << name3;
stream << " to play cards, while " << name4 << " played the violin.";

std::string sentence = stream.str();
```

Comment: I must have referred to this answer at least 10 times in the past few months.   For some reason, I keep forgetting.  If I could upvote you more, I would. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use boost::format for this:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/format/index.html

```
std::string result = boost::str(
    boost::format("%s and %s sat down with %s, to play cards, while %s played the violin")
      % name1 % name2 % name3 %name4
)
```

This is is a very simple example of what boost::format can do, it is a very powerful library.

Answer (score 1):

You can call member functions like `operator+=` on temporaries. Unfortunately, it has the wrong associativity, but we can fix that with parenthesis.

```
std::string sentence(((((((name1  +  " and ")
                        += name2) += " sat down with ")
                        += name3) += " to play cards, while ")
                        += name4) += " played the violin.");
```

It's a little ugly, but it doesn't involve any unneeded temporaries.